# Install Torndb in to Open Shift

Tags: python, mysql, tornado, openshift

im trying to implement a python"Tonado" application that needs to use MySQL as the database. So i need to configure Torndb with the OpenShift free account of mine. Im using Puti SSH Shell for the installation purpose. Since either "pip" or "easy-install" is not working in SSH Shell i tryied to run the setup.py file by my self.

but when i'm trying to run following command

```
 $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/bin/python setup.py install
```

as the final command, it throws me the following error

```
bash: /var/lib/openshift/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/app-root/data//bin/python: No such file or    directory
[abctrd-webturn.abctest.com torndb-master]\> OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/bin/python setup.py install
bash: OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that python is installed in your $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/bin/python.  How about trying just "python install"  and see what happens?